# can't download music files purchased with ubuntu one from rhythmbox

Tags: ubuntu-one, 12.04, rhythmbox

I used the link to Ubuntu One in Rhythmbox music player to purchase music.  On the My Downloads page from Ubuntu One in the Rhythmbox it shows each of the files I purchased with and mp3 button and an AAC button.  I should be able to download the files from these buttons but when I click on the button nothing happens - I was expecting a download manager to open up.

I also was expecting the files to be transferred to my UbuntuOne account but don't see anything there either. (this is probably a second question)

I am using 12.04 beta version of Ubuntu and the version of Rhythmbox that came with it: 2.96.

Do I need to install something to be able to download these links?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you purchase music through the Ubuntu One Music Store the files are immediately associated with your account, and are downloaded in the background automatically. The music is stored in ~/.ubuntuone/Purchased from Ubuntu One/, and it should show up in your Rhythmbox library without requiring a separate import.

Comment: Thanks.  I now see folders relating to my purchase in my ~/.ubuntuone/Purchased folder (there wasn't anything before) but they are empty.  Maybe it is taking a while for them to be updated.  I will wait a couple hours and see if I get any files in there.

Answer (score 0):

Did you complete the purchase? Clicking "Download" on a track in the store will take you to the "My Basket" page, where you should see a "Checkout" button. You can go back and add more items to your cart, or just check out from there. If you haven't actually purchased any music, then it won't download. If you go to the "My downloads" link at the top of the store, it will show you the songs you have purchased, and their download status.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I went back to the My downloads page and I now see the status as being Queued.  That is more promising than before.  So I think I might just have to wait for the downloads to happen.

Comment: @Andrea If you still haven't received your music in a few hours, you should open a support request at https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/ rather than asking questions on here. askUbuntu isn't really a place for reporting problems like this. Thanks. :)

Comment: Well, it looks like everything is here now.  It was just a time delay in the files getting transferred.  I appreciate your help.  I thought this was a problem with opening mp3 files and even though I still don't know why that didn't work - now I don't mind because the files were transferred and I don't need to run them that way.